# student visa for class less than 90 days in Spain

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, spain, student-visas

I've applied to an exchange program in Spain starting in January 2024, and was hoping sort out the visa soon.

My classes itself run for less than 90 days (~75 days total), which means that I am eligible for the Schengen type C visa, from what I understand. However, I was hoping to arrive early/leave late to settle in, move out, and travel a little afterwards, which would go over 90 days. I was wondering if I would be eligible for a type D national visa in this situation (ex. the short-term study visa in Spain for 3-6 month travelers). If not, I was wondering if there is any way to get the Schengen study visa & stack the normal 90 days I have as a visa-free passport holder (which is something that someone mentioned to me) to travel and have a bit of flexibility in the moving in process.

I would just love to do some travelling around while I am there (before or after classes), so if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You don't mention your nationality, so it's difficult to know what laws apply to your situation.

Comment: @enlguy i hold a south korean passport (but am studying in Canada as a Canadian PR - if that makes any difference)